# configure an object property descriptor

Tags: javascript

Using `Object.defineProperty()` You can define a property on an object.
It isn't like defining an object property using the literals' syntax, ex:

```js
const obj = {}
// then,
obj.x = "Hello"
```

It gives you more options where you can configure the property descriptor of an object, ex:

```
const obj = {}
Object.defineProperty(obj, "y", {
  writable: false,
  value: "You can't overwrite me"
})
console.log(obj) // { y: "You can't overwrite me" }
obj.y = "Hallo again"
console.log(obj) // { y: "You can't overwrite me" } 

// -- (would throw an error in strict mode)
```

This is cool.

Say for example I have the example above, and I have defined the property "y" and set its property descriptor property `writable: false`, and I wanted to change that.

Is there a way JavaScript provides a method to do so?

for example, a static method such as:

```
// of course this doesn't work, but just to point to the idea. 
Object.updatePropertyDescriptor(x, "y", { writable: true })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't when the property `configurable` is set to `false` which is the default value.

Besides the `writable` property you may also set `configurable` and `enumerable` on an object. When `configurable` is set to true you can use `Object.defineProperty()` again and change the property back to being writable if you like.

Let me illustrate this with an example:

```js
const obj = {}
Object.defineProperty(obj, "y", {
  writable: false,
  configurable: true,
  value: "You can't overwrite me"
})
console.log(obj.y) // "You can't overwrite me"
obj.y = "Hallo again"
console.log(obj.y) // "You can't overwrite me"
// since it's configurable we can define the property again
// otherwise we would get an error saying we can't 
// redefine the property
Object.defineProperty(obj, "y", {
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  value: "I can override you since you're configurable"
})
console.log(obj.y); //  "I can override you since you're configurable"
Object.defineProperty(obj, "y", {
  writable: false,
  configurable: false,
  value: "I cannot be overridden or redefined"
})
console.log(obj.y); //  "I cannot be overridden or redefined"
// throws error
Object.defineProperty(obj, "y", {
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  value: "Trying to override non-configurable property throws error"
})
```

More details on those properties can be found in this [blog post](http://arqex.com/967/javascript-properties-enumerable-writable-configurable).

Answer (score 3):

This is only possible if the object is `configurable` ([MDN: Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)).

```js
const obj = {}
Object.defineProperty(obj, "y", {
  writable: false,
  configurable: true,
  value: "You can't overwrite me"
})

console.log(1, obj.y) // { y: "You can't overwrite me" }

obj.y = "Hallo again"
console.log(2, obj.y) // { y: "You can't overwrite me" } 

Object.defineProperty(obj, "y", {
  writable: true,
});

obj.y = "Hallo again"
console.log(3, obj.y) // { y: "Hallo again" } 

Object.defineProperty(obj, "y", {
  writable: false,
});

obj.y = "You can't overwrite me"
console.log(4, obj.y) // { y: "Hallo again" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`configurable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) attributes to do this. It is mentioned in the documentation that-

> When `configurable` is set to false,
>
> other attributes of its descriptor cannot be changed (however if it's
> a data descriptor with writable: true, the value can be changed, and
> writable can be changed to false).

This means if `configurable` is set to true, the `writable` can be updated. Here is the demo-

```js
const obj = {}
Object.defineProperty(obj, "y", {
  writable: false,
  value: "You can't overwrite me",
  configurable: true,
  
})
console.log(obj.y) // { y: "You can't overwrite me" }
obj.y = "Hallo again"
console.log(obj.y) // { y: "You can't overwrite me" } 

// -- (would throw an error in strict mode)

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'y', {
  value: 'Now you can overwrite me',
  writable: true,
});

console.log(obj.y);
// Expected output: 'Now you can overwrite me'
```