# How to call a method from a distinct component using Vue 3 & Pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I want to call an inner function of a component if I click a button. There are many suggestions using shared data, but it should work separately for different components. Here's an example:

```
// Page.vue
<template>
    <MyComponent my-prop="abc"/>
    <button @click="???">ButtonX</button>

    <MyComponent my-prop="123"/>
    <button @click="???">ButtonY</button>
</template>
// ...
```

```
// MyComponent.vue:
<script>
    function foo() {
        //Do something inside this component
    }
</script>
// ...
```

My goal is that if I press **ButtonX** then `foo()` function called for `<MyComponent my-prop="abc"/>` but if I press **ButtonY** the same inner `foo()` function runs for  `<MyComponent my-prop="123"/>`.
How could I achieve that? (The components could be far from each other in the component tree.)

I prefer solution using only Vue 3 and Pinia.

Comment: You can emit events from the sender component to the receiver component using `$root.$emit`. See this answer if helps- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75457666/11834856

Comment: "he components could be far from each other in the component tree" - consider showing your case further, the closer it to your real one, the more useful an answer can be. Is button always the sibling of MyComponent and does foo(myProp) on click? Then it's better for it to be a part of MyComponent, or be provided through a slot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ref`:

```
<template>
  <MyComponent myProp="abc" ref="a" />
  <button @click="handle('a')">ButtonX</button>

  <MyComponent myProp="123" ref="b" />
  <button @click="handle('b')">ButtonY</button>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent,
  },
  setup() {
    const a = ref(null);
    const b = ref(null);

    const handle = (refName) => {
      const ref = refName === "a" ? a : b;
      ref.value.foo();
    };

    return {
      a,
      b,
      handle,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! One important note for `<script setup>` users from the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component): "An exception here is that components using `<script setup>` are **private by default**: a parent component referencing a child component using `<script setup>` won't be able to access anything unless the child component chooses to expose a public interface using the `defineExpose` macro"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ref feature:

```html
        <template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld ref="helloComponent1" msg="hello" />
    <button @click="callComponent('helloComponent1')">ButtonX</button>
    <HelloWorld ref="helloComponent2" msg="hi" />
    <button @click="callComponent('helloComponent2')">ButtonY</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  methods: {
    callComponent(refKey) {
      console.log(this.$refs[refKey].say());
    },
  },
};
</script>


    <template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  methods: {
    say() {
      alert(this.msg);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: you can see the runing case on https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-2s5vsf?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).